# excel - find and highlight text from one sheet on second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting killed by excel, I'm not 100% sure it can do exactly what I'm needing.  I've tried various functions and can come close, but none are perfect.  I've [uploaded](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6OAPgcasG7RV2hmTUtYYlRYUHM/edit?usp=sharing) a spreadsheet as an example.  I have a sheet of mailboxes, followed by a cell with the users who have access to the mailbox.  The cell has anywhere from 0 to 5 users separated by commas.  The second sheet has a list of users.  What I need is a way to parse out the first sheet, either highlight on the first sheet, or copy to another sheet; all the mailboxes that all the associated users match in the second cell appear on the second sheet.

The real world sheet I have has over 2500 mailboxes with as many as 205 (as few as 0) associated users, so I desperately need a way to mechanically filter the sheet.  I'm trying to filter the mailboxes that all the associated users are present on a second sheet.

I've tried using vlookup, index/match and a few others, and what seems to trip it up is having the comma separation.  Using "*"& cell_i'm_looking_for &"*" returns nothing so I'm guessing I need to try something else.  I also have the sheet with all the users in separate cells.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your sheet and created a module with the following function inside of it:

```
Function mymailboxes(who As Range, lookup As Range)

Dim myRow As Range

For Each myRow In lookup

    If InStr(myRow.Cells(1, 2).Value, who.Value) > 0 Then

        myReturn = myReturn & "," & myRow.Cells(1, 1).Value

    End If

Next

'cut off the first ,

myReturn = Right(myReturn, Len(myReturn) - 1)

mymailboxes = myReturn

End Function
```

Then on Sheet 2, Cell E2 I gave the following formula: `=mymailboxes(A2, Sheet1!A1:B50)` which gave me the following results: `mailbox1,mailbox2,mailbox4,mailbox8,mailbox12,mailbox17,mailbox21,mailbox25,mailbox28,mailbox34,mailbox39,mailbox41,mailbox42,mailbox44,mailbox49,mailbox50`

I hope this helps.

To get a list of invalid users the following function will help.

```
Function get_invalid_users(users As Range, validusers As Range)

Dim myRow As Range

myusers = Split(users, ",")
myReturn = ""

For Each user In myusers

    is_valid_user = False
    'Guilty until proven innocent

    For Each myRow In validusers

        If myRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = user Then

            is_valid_user = True
            'Proven innocent, break out of the loop, no double jeopardy.
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    If is_valid_user = False Then

        myReturn = myReturn & "," & user

    End If

Next

If Len(myReturn) > 0 Then

    myReturn = Right(myReturn, Len(myReturn) - 1)

Else

    myReturn = ""

End If

get_invalid_users = myReturn

End Function
```

Sheet 1, Cell C2 with formula: `=get_invalid_users(B2, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)` returned `zx1234`

Comment: It does help, thanks!  One question though, is there a way to have it verify that all the users on the mailbox are listed on the second sheet?  Like, on the first sheet, the first mailbox, all three users are on sheet2, but mailbox2 is not true.  The module above will help me find all the mailboxes that a particular user is on, much appreciated!

Comment: No problem.  Yes that is possible I will edit my answer with an `get_invalid_users` function as well.